# Permissions management in Access Applications for SharePoint Online

Tags: permissions, app, database, access

Is there a way to limit the access level to an Access App in SharePoint Online?

i.e. I want to deploy a common database application for many users but I don't want that each user be able to view/edit the data introduced by other users.

I've addressed this issue by creating as many sites as users (with is own permission assigned), installing the Access app in each of theses sites and then downloading data from each site and fusing it in another database;

This solves the problem for 4-5 users, but for 45 users it seems unpractical (and tedious).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no,  that is one of the drawbacks. Each time you create an app, the database is actually created in azure. There is no way to separate user’s ability to edit and read various tables. In other words, it does not support role based permissions.